# Pass filenames dynamically to FlatFileItemWriter through StepBuilderFactory stream() when using ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor in SpringBatch

Tags: spring-batch, itemwriter, itemprocessor

I'm processing multiple input files with multi-format lines using `ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor`. But when using `StepBuilderFactory` stream to write the files, I'm unable to pass the `Resource` filename dynamically. Filename should be the respective input file name. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Input File 1 (data-111111-12323.txt)**

```
1#9999999#00001#2#RecordType1
2#00002#June#Statement#2020#9#RecordType2
3#7777777#RecordType3
```

**Input File 2 (data-22222-23244.txt)**

```
1#435435#00002#2#RecordType1
2#345435#July#Statement#2021#9#RecordType2
3#645456#RecordType3
```

**Expected output file 1 (data-111111-12323.txt)**

```
1#9999999#00001#2#RecordType1#mobilenumber1
2#00002#June#Statement#2020#9#RecordType2#mobilenumber2
3#7777777#RecordType3#mobilenumber3
```

**Expected output file 2 (data-22222-23244.txt)**

```
1#9999999#00001#2#RecordType1#mobilenumber1
2#00002#June#Statement#2020#9#RecordType2#mobilenumber2
3#7777777#RecordType3#mobilenumber3
```

**Step**

```
        public Step partitionStep() throws Exception {
            ItemReader reader = context.getBean(FlatFileItemReader.class);
            ClassifierCompositeItemWriter writer = context.getBean(ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.class);
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("statementProcessingStep.slave").<String, String>chunk(12).reader(reader).processor(processor()).writer(writer)
                    .stream(recordType0FlatFileItemWriter())
                    .stream(recordType1FlatFileItemWriter())
                    .build();
                }
```

**Processor**

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor processor() {
            ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<? extends RecordType, ? extends RecordType> processor = new ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor<>();
SubclassClassifier classifier = new SubclassClassifier();
        Map typeMap = new HashMap();
        typeMap.put(RecordType0.class, recordType0Processor);
        typeMap.put(RecordType1.class, recordType1Processor);
classifier.setTypeMap(typeMap);
        processor.setClassifier(classifier);
return processor;
}
```

**Writer**

```
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<RecordType1> recordType1FlatFileItemWriter() throws Exception{
        FlatFileItemWriter<RecordType1> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setResource( new FileSystemResource("record1.txt")); //This filename should be dynamic
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<RecordType1>() {{
            setDelimiter("#");
            setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<RecordType1>() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "RecordType", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3"});
                }
            });
        }});
        return  writer;
    }
```

Comment: Are "Input File 1" and "Input File 1" passed as job parameters? If yes, you can create a step-scoped writer and use late-binding to inject the file from job parameters at runtime, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding

Comment: Genius! Just adding a @StepScope worked! Thank you tons!!!

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I had to change the implementation to synchronous batch processing as I had to implement `PeekableItemReader`. So couldn't have Partitioning. In this scenario, `StepScope` didn't work. Since the files are read from a folder, I used `ResourceAware` to set the current resource in Reader. But I'm unable to retrieve the resource name in `ItemWriter`. I've asked a separate question. Could you please have a look? 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66624001/spring-batch-resourceaware-get-resource-name-in-classifiercompositeitemwriter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your item reader/writer step-scoped and inject values from job parameters or step/job execution context using late-binding. For example:

```
@StepScope
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader flatFileItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}") String name) {
   return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Foo>()
        .name("flatFileItemReader")
        .resource(new FileSystemResource(name))
        .build();
}
```

You can find more details in the [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) section of the reference documentation.